# is it feasible to save the public IP of the user in my API in case of a thef of a jwt?

Tags: node.js, api, security, jwt, ip

I was thinking about how to secure my API and prevent token theft from affecting my users. I thought it would be a good idea to save my users IP if an attacker manages to steal a token and is used by one with a different IP. I'm going to use a middleware or a function to verify if it is in the user ip list and if not I'm going to reject his token and then ask for your credentials in the frontend. If the credentials are correct I will overwrite the  IP or store it as a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you mean by "is it feasible".  Yes, you can do it if you want.

But, there are plenty of potential issues with relying on a user's IP address not changing and forcing them to reauthenticate every time it does change.

**1. Mobile devices moving around.**  As mobile devices move on a cellular network, their IP address can legitimately change.

**2. Mobile devices connecting to different networks (such as WiFi).**  As your phone goes from being in your car and on the cellular network to being at home and on your WiFi network, that phone's IP address in connecting to your service will change.

**3. NAT behind some firewall.**  Nearly every user (even home users) are going through a NAT device and the IP address you're seeing is the IP address of a gateway, not the actual user's IP address.  In a larger corporate network, the gateway IP address may not always be the same.  And, multiple different users may appear to be from the same gateway IP address so there is not necessarily a one-to-one correspondence between users and IP addresses.

---

In general, you should just be using https for all connections in which you transmit the JWT so there is little risk of man-in-the-middle attacks stealing the JWT.  The user themselves needs to secure their own local storage of the JWT.

An approach used by many modern services is to [fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) the local device by recording a set of characteristics it has which may even include the presence of some other cookie along with a number of other browser characteristics.  Then, you require reauthentication whenever the fingerprint changes by some significant amount.  You will see many bank and airline websites doing something like this.  The idea here is that even if the credential is stolen, then the fingerprint is unlikely to match when a credential is being used by an attacker.